# How can an ag-Grid cell editor in Svelte prompt the user to confirm a change?

Tags: editor, cell, ag-grid, svelte, confirm

I have an ag-Grid in a Svelte file.
One of the column definitions is for a floating point number displayed to 2 places of decimals, like this:

```
const columnDefinitions = [
    ...
    {
        field: fixedScr,
        headerName: "Fixed SCR",
        cellClass: numberCellClassSelector,
        type: "rightAligned",
        width: 150,
        editable: true,
        valueFormatter: numberFormatterFactory(2),
        valueParser: numberParser,
    },
    ...
];
```

I have chosen the ag-Grid as a convenient means of displaying and editing a column of these values.  However, my Product Owner wants the web page to challenge the user every time they make a change to a cell with an "Are you sure?" prompt.

A bit heavy-handed, perhaps, as it will make editing with the ag-Grid somewhat slower.  But these values will be change infrequently, and changes should be made with care.

How would I define a simple cell editor, just for this column, which prompts the user to confirm a change before the grid is updated?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose binding into an ag-grid event which is triggered once a value is updated. on the callback (which should by an async function).

my implementation will go as follow create a `Popup.svelte` component.

you will also create a store, which i will call `popup` in a global js file for example `store.js`.

you will then import `popup` from `store.js` in `Popup.svelte`. then you will set the value of the `popup` store to an async function which will interact with the HTML of `Popup.svelte`. this async function will return a `promise` which you will await in your other svelte components while using the `popup` store.

in this Promise you will await all previous popups to close to show your current popup, you will supply the title, and the return values of the buttons which will be shown in the popup

here is an example of the implementation of the code i made

```svelte
<style>
    .u-overlay {
        min-height: 100vh;
        max-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index: 50000;
    }

    .u-box {
        width: 500px;
        background-color: white;
        min-height: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .u-title {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .u-desc {
        padding: 20px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .u-buttons {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px 0;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .u-over-button {
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px 0;

        -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
        -webkit-user-select: none; 
        -khtml-user-select: none; 
        -moz-user-select: none; 
        -ms-user-select: none; 
        user-select: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>


<script>
    import { popup } from "../utils.js";
    import { fade } from "svelte/transition";

    let overlay;
    let template = {
        title: "Write title",
        desc: "Please select",
        buttons: [
            { name: "OK", value: true, color: "#F0F0F0" },
            { name: "Decline", value: false, color: "red" },
        ],
    };
    let popData = undefined;
    let promises = [];
    let colorsConver = {
        ok: "#46b978",
        danger: "#d23149",
    };

    popup.set(async (data) => {
        /* we got a new sub*/
        /* start the promise for the future click */
        let pro = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            /* make sure all promises before this one are done */
            await Promise.all(promises);
            /* when they are done start the overlay for this sub */

            /* convert text to appropriate hex */
            for (let btn of data.buttons) {
                if (colorsConver[btn.color]) {
                    btn.color = colorsConver[btn.color];
                }
            }
            popData = data;
            setTimeout(() => {
                overlay.addEventListener(
                    "click",
                    (event) => {
                        if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) return;
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        console.log("from overlay");

                        resolve(data.buttons[data.buttons.length - 1].value);
                        popData = undefined;
                    },
                    {
                        once: true,
                        capture: true,
                    }
                );
                for (let b of [
                    ...document.querySelectorAll(".u-overlay .u-buttons"),
                ]) {
                    b.addEventListener(
                        "click",
                        (event) => {
                            event.stopPropagation();
                            console.log("ending button");

                            resolve(event.target.dataset.res);
                            popData = undefined;
                        },
                        {
                            once: true,
                            capture: true,
                        }
                    );
                }
            }, 130);
        });
        /* add this promise so the future ones wait it*/
        promises.push(pro);
        return pro;
    });

    import { popup } from "path/to/store.js";
    const someFunction = () => {
        let resp = await $popup({
            title: "Write title",
            desc: "Please select",
            buttons: [
                { name: "OK", value: true, color: "#F0F0F0" },
                { name: "Decline", value: false, color: "red" },
            ],
        });
    };
</script>


{#if popData}
    <div
        bind:this={overlay}
        transition:fade={{ duration: 150 }}
        class="u-overlay"
    >
        <div on:click|stopPropagation|preventDefault class="u-box">
            <div class="u-title">{popData.title}</div>
            <p class="u-desc">{popData.desc}</p>
            <div class="u-buttons">
                {#each popData.buttons as b}
                    <div
                        data-res={b.value}
                        class="u-over-button"
                        style={"background-color:" + b.color}
                    >
                        {b.name}
                    </div>
                {/each}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{/if}
```

in other components

```svelte
<script>
    import { popup } from "path/to/store.js";
    const someFunction = () => {
        let resp = await $popup({
            title: "Write title",
            desc: "Please select",
            buttons: [
                { name: "OK", value: true, color: "#F0F0F0" },
                { name: "Decline", value: false, color: "red" },
            ],
        });
    };
</script>
```